# Is there a "uniform" Folner sequence consisting of balls for f.p. groups with polynomial growth?

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, amenability

Let $G$ be a finitely presented group with polynomial growth. Fix a generating set for $G$.

For every subgroup $H$ of $G$, element $g\in G$ and positive number $R$, define $\alpha(H,g,R)$ to be $|\partial B(gH,R)|/|B(gH,R)|$ where $B(gH,R)$ is the ball in the Schreier graph $G/H$ with center $gH$ and radius $R$.

For every positive number $R$, define $\alpha(R)$ as the supremum of the $\alpha(H,g,R)$ where $H$ runs over all finite index subgroups of $G$ and $g$ runs over all elements of $G$.

Is there a sequence for radii $R_1,R_2,R_3,\dotsc$ tending to infinity such that $\alpha(R_i)$ tends to zero as $i$ tends to infinity?

Comment: @YCor: I too believe "supremum" was meant here, but note that $H$ only runs over *finite index* subgroups.

Comment: @YCor: I know how to show that balls are Folner in groups of subexponential growth, but (the supremum version of) this question asks for more, doesn't it? I would like to know the answer too.

Comment: For the 1st half of your last comment: what's clear is that in every group of subexp. growth, some *sub*sequence *extracted* from balls is Følner. But that all balls are Følner is known in polynomial growth, but not trivial at all, and unknown in intermediate growth.

Comment: OK, my argument (for sup) is not exactly enough (having in mind the pathology of Følner subsets mentioned in  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283824): if $e_r\to 0$ is such that in $G$ we have $|\partial B(r)|/|B(r)|=e_r$, then $e_r$ tends to 0, and we'd expect $e_r$ to be an upper bound in Schreier graphs as well, but there's an issue in case the ball is not mapped injectively. We'd need to know, roughly, that if the balled is mapped "very non-injectively", then so is its boundary; it sounds plausible. The other approach is to use almost invariant functions instead of Følner subsets!

Comment: @YCor: Thanks for the correction, indeed I meant to say "supremum". Edited accordingly.

Comment: @YCor: Here's an idea: If the degree of the polynomial growth of $G$ is $d$, then (very nontrivially) the growth goes like $Cd^r$ for some constant $d$ (not only a upper bound, but almost exactly), and so the ratio $|\partial B(r)|/|B(r)|$ is at most $d/r$. For quotients the same is true with an even smaller (at least, not larger) degree $d$. Does this seem right? If so, then it settles the version of the question were we're only looking at quotients by normal subgroups, and we're left with generalizing to general subgroups (maybe this was obvious to you, I'm still a beginner in this field).

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the general case to the case of normal subgroups by taking a finite index normal subgroup of the not necessarily normal subgroup? I'm not sure - because running over different subgroups we get covers of unbounded degree (I mean: the Schreier graph of G/H covering the Cayley graph G/N for some N normal in G and contained in H).

Comment: Your estimates are not very precisely stated... first you mean that the growth $b(r)=Cr^d+o(r^d)$ for some $C$, this is indeed true and nontrivial, but this is not enough to infer that $b(r+1)-b(r)=O(r^{-1})$, and even to go to normal subgroups you need the asymptotic expansion $Cr^d+O(r^{d-1})$ to hold in a uniform way (= with constant depending only on the number of generators, degree of growth and index of a nilpotent subgroup), I'm not sure if it's known, you could check Breuillard's papers.

Comment: @YCor: Sorry for the inaccuracies. Did you mean $(b(r+1)-b(r))/b(r)=O(r^{-1})$?

Comment: Yes (I meant $b(r+1)-b(r)=O(r^{d-1})$)